# How to not let Curl replace space with quotes?

Tags: bash, variables, curl, quotes, space

I'm writing a bash script to launch curl requests
I'm reading the input of the user and save it an variable

*read theterm*

Let's say the user typed :

"Hello World"

I am passing the variable to the curl request as follow :

**curl 'https://someurl.com' -H ... --data '{"term":'$theterm',....}'**

So while debugging my data looked like :

--data {"term" :**"Hello' 'World"**...}

while it was supposed to be :

--data {"term" : **"Hello World"**....}

Any suggestions ?

Comment: [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: `--data "{\"term\": \"$theterm\"}"`

Comment: @tripleee your comment worked when i removed the quotes since the user enters : "Hello World" i had to use the sed command to remove the quotes . Thank you

Comment: Just `${theterm//\"/}` should do it; no need for an external process.